# mysql how to index a column right?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, collation

I've got a table looking like:

| id | comment_id | create_date | text_content | parent_id | completed | parent_case_number | parent_database_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23244 | 55a3200000jm4Y1AAI | 2015-10-27 18:26:37 | very long text | 5088200005o0G6sAAE | 1 | 1000005 | 4 |

I'm trying to fill the table by queries like this:

```
UPDATE case_base.comment 
    SET parent_case_database_id = '4' , 
        parent_case_num = '3242' 
WHERE parent_id = '5088200005o0G6sAAE';
```

It's taking about 9 seconds to complete this query. The problem is that I need to update 6 000 000 of such lines.

It could take near 2 years to complete.

Is it possible to add any index or speed this all up somehow?

Comment: When asking query optimization questions, please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>` and include the result in your question. Also run `EXPLAIN` for your SQL query and include the result in your question. And run `SELECT VERSION()` and tell us exactly what that returns.

Comment: That said, I expect the only index that would help this `UPDATE` would be on the `parent_id` column. If you don't have that index, then add it.

Comment: If you already have an index on that column, and the updates are still taking 9 seconds each, then something else is going on. Lock contention, high load, or else you're running your database on a severely underpowered server.

Comment: *.. SET parent_case_database_id = '4' , parent_case_num = '3242' ..* - no such columns.

Comment: LIkely the performance issue here is because you put a large chunk of non-relational data ( `text_content`) inside a relational table.  You'd likely get better performance if you moved that content to a separate table and then joined back together to get the text content when you wanted it.

Comment: Whenever you ask about SQL query optimization, **show the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: Thank you all! You were all correct indeed. Next time I'll be more accurate & detailed in questions + I'll put the heaviest column to a separate table. The query CREATE INDEX parent_id_index ON case_base.comment (parent_id); made the trick

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider:

1. If possible you should define your `parent_id` column to include `COLLATE 'ascii_bin'`, something like this.

   ```sql
   parent_id CHAR(18) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin'
   ```

   If those `parent_id` values like `'5088200005o0G6sAAE'` aren't sure to be 18 characters long like the one in your example, you can use `VARCHAR(something)` instead.

   The `latin1_bin` collation means the values for that column will be stored and compared as case-sensitive 8-bit characters. That makes the columns and the indexes more compact and therefore slightly faster. (The default in MySQL and MariaDB these days is something like `utf8mb4_general_ci`, which is case-insensitive and takes 32 bits per character in indexes.)

   Plus, you have lower case characters in your example, so you should think twice before using a case-insensitive collation ... it may cause your `WHERE parent_id = '5088200005o0G6sAAE'` filter to hit more rows than you intended.

   Other columns that don't need multinational characters should also use that `latin1_bin` collation.  Your `text_content` column probably does need multinational characters.

2. This index will accelerate your UPDATE query. The efficient collation will be baked into the index.

   ```sql
   CREATE INDEX parent_id ON your_table (parent_id);
   ```
3. If you do your updates in transaction batches of, maybe, a hundred or so at a time things will go faster. Something like this.

   ```sql
   START TRANSACTION;
   UPDATE whatever;
   UPDATE whatever;
   ... 98 more...
   COMMIT;
   START TRANSACTION;
   ... 100 more ...
   COMMIT;
   ...
   ```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer improved my understanding of this. I'd add only one correction to your answer. CREATE INDEX parent_id ON your_table (parent_id); failed because the table already has the column name parent_id. The correct query is something like: CREATE INDEX parent_id_index ON case_base.comment (parent_id);

Comment: Thanks for that. The thing is, index names can be anything, as long as they are unique index names for the table. If you got a name collision error when creating the index named `parent_id`, it means your table already has an **index** by that name. You might want to double check what you have with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.